# BRISK in javaCV - How to initialize the descriptor matrix?

Tags: java, opencv, computer-vision, javacv

I am trying to run BRISK within java using the openCV wrapper javacv. I don't have any problems running a FAST corner detector but I am stuck on how to run the compute function. When I run this code:

```
private int threshold = 30;
private int octaves = 3;
private float scale = 1.0f;

private BRISK brisk = null;
private KeyPoint keyPoints = null;
private CvMat img, descriptors;

descriptors = new CvMat();
keyPoints = new KeyPoint();

img = getFrame();

brisk = new BRISK(threshold, octaves, scale);
brisk.compute(img, null, keyPoints, descriptors, false);
```

I get following error:

> OpenCV Error: Bad argument (Unknown array type) in unknown function,
>   file ......\src\opencv\modules\core\src\matrix.cpp, line 698

I am sure that the img is not the problem because I can run a FAST corner detection on it. I think the actual problem is the descriptors matrix because I have no clue how to initialize it. Any ideas?

Comment: I am using OpenCv Java 2.4.9 but I could not find a way to create BRISK object as you have done above code. Which package did you import to do so, also which version of JavaCv were you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution to the problem is the descriptors need to be initialized as new CvMat(null)